# Converting double,double to double []

Tags: java

When i try and run my code, i get this error:
error: method getTest1 in class Assess cannot be applied to given types;

 double fit = Assess.getTest1(sol1[0],sol1[1]);
^

 required: double[]

 found: double,double

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I cant find a fix. Any help would be much appriciated. Thanks

```
double[] sol1={100,100};
        double fit = Assess.getTest1(sol1[0],sol1[1]);
        
        boolean successful = false;
        int a = 0; // a is to ensure we don't waste time if we keep getting shitty initial pops
        double goodFit = 0.001;
        while(!successful) { 
        System.out.println(a++);
            double[][] pop1 = initialPop1();
            double[][] bestPop1 = findBestPop(pop1, 100);
            
            double[][] modifiedPop1 = crossover1(bestPop1, 100);
            double[][] bestModPop1 = findBestPop(modifiedPop1, 25);
            
            double bestFit = 100; // temp stores best fitness of this pop
            for(int i = 0; i < bestModPop1.length; i++) {
                fit = Assess.getTest1(bestModPop1[i][0],bestModPop1[i][1]);
                if(a==2) { goodFit = 0.01; } else if (a==3) { goodFit = 0.1; }
                if(fit < goodFit && fit > 0) {
                    successful = true;
                    if(fit < bestFit) {
                        bestFit = fit;
                        sol1[0] = bestModPop1[i][0];
                        sol1[1] = bestModPop1[i][1];
                    }
                } 
            }
```

Comment: It would really help if we could see the entire code of getTest().

Comment: Could you share all the relevant source like `Assess.getTest` and the full stack trace please?

Comment: It would appear that getTest1() expects a `double[] array`.  But can't be certain of anything until you provide more detail.

Comment: Although by looking at it, it looks like you need to put `bestModPop1[i][0],bestModPop1[i][1]` into an array before passing it to getTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, we can deduce that the method is declared like this:

```java
static double getTest1(double[] x) { ...
```

You have 3 choices:

1. Pass the array you already have:

   ```java
   double[] sol1={100,100};
   double fit = Assess.getTest1(sol1);
   ```
2. Create a temporary array for the 2 values:

   ```java
   double fit = Assess.getTest1(new double[] { sol1[0], sol1[1] });
   ```
3. Change the method to varargs:

   ```java
   static double getTest1(double... x) { ...
   ```

   You can then call it like you did:

   ```java
   double fit = Assess.getTest1(sol1[0], sol1[1]);
   ```

If you can modify the `getTest1()` method, I'd recommend option #3.